# Java integrated SQL server

Tags: java, sql-server

I'm working on a plugin for an emulator that is going to allow people to host a control panel through a website to view statistics, etc; Currently I have XAMPP installed which is running my SQL Server, and the HTTP Server is being handled through the `Netty` networking library in Java.

I'm curious as to if there is a way to host the SQL Server from within Java, similar to the HTTP Server. It'd also greatly simplify the process of installation for the plugin.

The other option was to use ObjectDB, but after looking into it, it seems like it requires `Quercus` and I don't want to go through that.

Comment: So, you're looking for an embedded Java database, is that right? Google for "embedded Java database".

Answer (score 0):

The term you're looking for is "embedded database".

There are a number of databases that you can use as an embedded database, and you can choose to use them as an in-memory database (which means the data is gone when your application stops) or make them save data to a file on disk, so that the data is still there when you stop and re-start the application.

Examples of databases that can be used in this way: [H2 Database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html), [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/), [Apache Derby](https://db.apache.org/derby/).